# Image with grid lines

Tags: graphics, image-processing

I have an image of a certain size.

```
img = Image[source, ImageSize -> escala];
```

I want to add a grid with a scale (0 to maxX from left to right and 0 to maxY from top to bottom). The problem is that `GridLines` is an option for `Graphics`, not for `Image`.

How can I overlay grid lines on my image?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
img = ExampleData[{"TestImage", "Lena"}];

grid = Graphics[{}, GridLines -> Automatic, PlotRangePadding -> None, 
  GridLinesStyle -> Directive[Red, Thick], ImageSize -> ImageDimensions@img];

Overlay[{img, grid}]
```

[image]

---

For arbitrary numbers `n+1` and `m+1` of equidistant gridlines with automatic dependence on the `ImageDimensions` of `img` (which does not have to be a square either):

```
n = 13;
m = 7;
sub1 = Subdivide[-1, 1, n];
sub2 = Subdivide[-1, 1, m];

grid = Graphics[{}, GridLines -> {sub1, sub2}, 
  PlotRangePadding -> None, GridLinesStyle -> Directive[Red, Thick], 
  ImageSize -> ImageDimensions@img];

Overlay[{img, grid}]
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much! it was very useful and clear. Now i can continue by my own.

Comment: I did, but i have a problem. It only createas a 4x4 grid. I tried to add more lines but i couldn't.

Comment: I need more "density" of lines and a way to control it.

The image have a imagesize=escale. I have to control something like "a line each escale/k"

Comment: @ShiroIgnis See the updated answer.

Comment: All right! i tested it and it was exactly as i want.

Comment: @corey979, thank you so much  for the generous bounty.

Answer (score 13):

You can use `Show` with gridlines specs combined with `Method -> {"GridLinesInFront" -> True}`:

```
img = ExampleData[{"TestImage", "Lena"}];

Show[img, GridLines -> {Range[0, #, #/10], Range[0, #2, #2/5]} & @@ 
  ImageDimensions[img], GridLinesStyle -> Directive[Thick, Red], 
 Method -> {"GridLinesInFront" -> True}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

You can also use `PlotStyle->Texture[img]` with, say, `RegionPlot`:

```
RegionPlot[0 <= x <= 1 && 0 <= y <= 1, {x, 0, 1}, {y, 0, 1}, 
 PlotStyle -> Texture[img], PlotRangePadding->0,
 GridLines -> {Range[0, 1, .1], Range[0, 1, .2]}, 
 GridLinesStyle -> Directive[Thick, Red], Frame -> False, 
 Method -> { "GridLinesInFront" -> True}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Finally, you can use `Mesh` instead of `GridLines`:

```
RegionPlot[0 <= x <= 1 && 0 <= y <= 1, {x, 0, 1}, {y, 0, 1}, 
 PlotStyle -> Texture[img], Mesh -> {9, 4}, 
 MeshStyle -> Directive[Thick, Red], Frame -> False]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]