# Grid shows next to image, not on actual image, and ImageDimensions are wrong

Tags: image-processing, version-10

I am still using Mathematica 10.3 and I have the following problem:

My code is as follows (based on what I found in a related post, see below,Note: I used another example image):

```
 img = ExampleData[{"AerialImage", "Pentagon"}];

 grid = Graphics[{}, GridLines -> Automatic, PlotRangePadding -> None, 
   GridLinesStyle -> Directive[Red, Thick], 
    ImageSize -> ImageDimensions@img];

 Overlay[{img, grid}];
```

The output is completely off -- the grid is much larger than the image. I also tried with an actual image I am interested in, and that gave me the same problem. It does work fine with the test image "Lena", but not with any other image.

However, if I check `ImageDimensions[img]` and `ImageDimensions[grid]`, I do get the same output. So it might just be that for some reason, all other images except for "Lena" give me a wrong output concerning the `ImageDimensions`, which is why the grid might be messed up.

Can anyone help with this? What can I do?

Thanks in advance!

P.S. My question is related to and my code is based on the question and answers here: [Image with grid lines](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/132085)

Comment: try `Overlay[{Show[img, ImageSize -> ImageDimensions@img], grid}]`?

Comment: try also the methods in [this answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/132094/125)

Comment: Hi, Thanks so much! Yeah, the other methods mentioned in the post you linked are the ones I read first. 

However,  your suggestion is already very helpful. My code now looks like this:

    n = 25;
    m = 25;
    sub1 = Subdivide[-1, 1, n];
    sub2 = Subdivide[-1, 1, m];

    grid = Graphics[{}, GridLines -> {sub1, sub2}, 
       PlotRangePadding -> None, GridLinesStyle -> Directive[Red, Thick], 
       ImageSize -> ImageDimensions@img];

    Overlay[{Show[img, ImageSize -> ImageDimensions@img], grid}]

Comment: This seems to work only for square images, though. My image is not square. Even if I change m and n, the grid will only appear in the middle of the image and it will be a square, even if the small grids are rectangles. 

How can I make sure the grid covers the entire image, not only the middle?

Comment: Marla, please see the answer I posted. I suggest you edit your answer to add the code in your comment.

Answer (score 2):

```
n = 10; m = 10;

img1 = ImageResize[img, {500, 500}];

id1 = ImageDimensions@img1;

gridlinesx1 = Subdivide[1, id1[[1]], n];
gridlinesy1 = Subdivide[1, id1[[2]], m];

prange1 = Thread[{1, id1}]; 
grid1 = Graphics[{}, GridLines -> {gridlinesx1, gridlinesy1}, 
  PlotRange -> prange1, PlotRangePadding -> None, 
  GridLinesStyle -> Directive[Red, Thick], ImageSize -> id1]; 
Overlay[{Show[img1, ImageSize -> id1], grid1}]
```

[image]

Use `m = 5` to get

[image]

The same approach works for a *non-square* image:

```
n = 10; m = 10;
img2 = ImageResize[img, {500, 300}];

id2 = ImageDimensions@img2;

gridlinesx2 = Subdivide[1, id2[[1]], n];
gridlinesy2 = Subdivide[1, id2[[2]], m];

prange2 = Thread[{1, id2}]; 

grid2 = Graphics[{}, GridLines -> {gridlinesx2, gridlinesy2}, 
  PlotRange -> prange2, PlotRangePadding -> None, 
  GridLinesStyle -> Directive[Red, Thick], ImageSize -> id2];

Overlay[{Show[img2, ImageSize -> id2], grid2}]
```

[image]

and with `m = 5`:

[image]